# What books should I buy to play with an average D&D group?

Tags: dnd-4e, books

I have already bought all three 4th edition Player's Handbooks, Dungeon Master's Guide, Monster Manual, dice, Dungeon Tiles, Plan escape tile map set, and several tubes of dice, but have recently learned that 4th edition isn't too popular with some subgroups of gamers. While the nearest game store is a state away (and thus will likely play online), I prefer having books to read in my spare time and want to one day join a physical group. My question is, **what books I buy so that I could easily join an average group of Dungeons and Dragons players of with few problems and without me inconveniencing people too much?**

Comment: Please edit your question and make it more clear - are you still planning to join a 4e group and you want to know what else besides the three books to get (dice and stuff), or wondering which version to buy to join the average group, or what?

Comment: To clarify if people wonder where I get my game stuff, there's a local Hastings where most 4-e stuff is out of stock, online as well so I can't order, and I don't buy online.

Comment: Due to question reframing, all extant answers have been deleted, as they do not speak to the current question.

Comment: DraconeKing, this question will remain on hold until you clarify what you're asking. Is this an edition-request question, or a "what other books do I need to play online" question? I would recommend avoiding terms like "average". Instead, identify *where* you want to play and *what* you want to play and *how* you want to play, and figure out which one of those three your question is about.

Comment: DraconeKing I still am not quite getting it, are you saying that since 4e isn't what every play group is playing, you imagine some other version is and you're asking what you need to buy for those other game(s)? (in which case BESW's answer was on point?)

Comment: I've found how this question has been handled frustrating, and I think that's because it *may* be a type of question/problem that we haven't developed clear consensus around. I've started [a meta here to discuss](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3505/how-do-we-handle-it-when-the-askers-problem-is-just-that-theyre-confused) this (possible) subtype of XY problem questions.

Comment: @mxyzplk For most bizarre it seens, It is exactly that. He want's to know which edition of D&D will get him on a group more easily, AKA "Which Edition of D&D is more popular" or "Which edition of D&D is played the most?", so he can study and focus on learning something that he will be able to play by just dropping in a group. English is not his mother tongue - I suppose is something more "Latim-like", since a word-by-word translation made perfect sense to me (from the original question, not the edited one)

Comment: I'f that's what he means, then he can easily clarify. If he's never coming back there's no point to answering his question, either.